# How to query mongodb to get data in following format?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

**Expected Query Output**

```
food = {
    'fruit': ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry'],
    'vegetables': ['onion', 'cucumber'],                                                 
}
```

**Data Format in Database**

```
    [{
    "category": "fruit",
    "name": "banana"
}, {
    "category": "fruit",
    "name": "apple"
}, {
    "category": "fruit",
    "name": "cherry"
}, {
    "category": "vegetables",
    "name": "onion"
}, {
    "category": "vegetables",
    "name": "cucumber"
}]
```

Basically, I need to fetch distinct category and list of names against it from mongodb.

TIA

Comment: Your data format is wrong. There can't be objects inside objects without keys. The outer most element must be an array, then only it will be a valid JSON.

Comment: Please suggest solution. Don't worry about json format. Its a dummy data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$category",
            "list": {
                "$addToSet": "$name"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "array": [{
                "k": "$_id",
                "v": "$list"
            }]
        }
    },
    {
        "$replaceRoot": {
            "newRoot": {
                "$arrayToObject": "$array"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Working eg. https://mongoplayground.net/p/bccPDlORK7W